Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
я пытался написать базовый код для телеграмм бота, в итоге ошибка в вообще другом каком то коде и бот не запускается.
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('7200420095:AAEjQjbo4YTmO8GpFkxqwYeYjWFyecx46Dg')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello')

bot.infinity_polling()

и ошибки
2024-06-22 08:01:05,498 (__init__.py:1221 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"
2024-06-22 08:01:05,499 (__init__.py:1223 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1214, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 676, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 648, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 330, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 168, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yerko\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 195, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
"


Дело в том, что у вас запущено два экземпляра бота. Убейте процесс с одним из ботов. Если вы не можете найти этот процесс в pycharm/vscode/консоли, воспользуйтесь диспетчером задач для принудительного завершения Python процесса
И да, токен бота лучше сменить, так как теперь любой желающий может запустить его вместо вас
